# Ionic: Ion-Select as required field

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5

I would like to make my `ion-select` a required input of the form, but it does not work like this. I do not use Angular or React.

```
<ion-select id= "id1" required>
//...
</ion-select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a template reference  to your ion-select named id1

```
<ion-select id= "id1" #id1 >
//...
</ion-select>
```

Access this ref to Typscript class:

```
  @ViewChild("id1") id1!: IonSelect;
```

Return to html page to check if it has a value to validate your submit button.

```
<ion-button [disabled]='!!id1 && !!id1.value'>Submit</ion-button>
```